# Example of raw vs managed state

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to understand the difference between raw and managed state. From the docs:

> Keyed State and Operator State exist in two forms: managed and raw.
>
> Managed State is represented in data structures controlled by the
>   Flink runtime, such as internal hash tables, or RocksDB. Examples are
>   “ValueState”, “ListState”, etc. Flink’s runtime encodes the states and
>   writes them into the checkpoints.
>
> Raw State is state that operators keep in their own data structures.
>   When checkpointed, they only write a sequence of bytes into the
>   checkpoint. Flink knows nothing about the state’s data structures and
>   sees only the raw bytes.

However, I have not found any example highlighting the difference. Can anyone provide a minimal example to make the difference clear in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator state is only used in Operator API which is intended only for power users and it's not as stable as the end-user APIs, which is why we rarely advertise it.
As an example, consider [AbstractUdfStreamOperator](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/8674b69964eae50cad024f2c5caf92a71bf21a09/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/operators/AbstractUdfStreamOperator.java#L87-L97), which represents an operator with an UDF. For checkpointing, the state of the UDF needs to be saved and on recovery restored.

```
@Override
public void snapshotState(StateSnapshotContext context) throws Exception {
    super.snapshotState(context);
    StreamingFunctionUtils.snapshotFunctionState(context, getOperatorStateBackend(), userFunction);
}

@Override
public void initializeState(StateInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
    super.initializeState(context);
    StreamingFunctionUtils.restoreFunctionState(context, userFunction);
}
```

At this point, the state could be serialized as just a byte blob. As long as the operator can restore the state by itself, the state can take an arbitrary shape.

However, coincidentally in the past, much of the operator states have also been (re-)implemented as managed state. So the line is more blurry in reality.

Comment: Thanks a lot Arvid. I guess that when you refer to *operator state* in your reply you mean *raw (operator) state*, since my question was about the difference between raw/managed state. To further clarify your point, could you provide a link to the Operator API or to some simple example using raw operator state? Unfortunately, it is still not clear to me how this looks like in code (all the example I've found in the docs so far are for managed state only).

Comment: The link is already the example: you use operator API if you implement your own operator. For example, Flink lets you implement your own join if you think you have a better one than the default implementation. For this operator, you can serialize whatever you want. But inside a UDF, you need to stick to managed state.

Comment: Also, I think the current docs for Flink are bit lacking on this regard. Correct me if I am wrong, but there is no example in the book "Stream Processing with Apache Flink: Fundamentals, Implementation, and Operation of Streaming Applications" by Fabian Hueske and Vasiliki Kalavri, either.

Comment: I have found [this](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/flink-user/201712.mbox/%3CetPan.5a3ae152.1b9f69a8.12b@apache.org%3E), which also touches upon the difference between raw and managed state.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is an example, but I'd doubt it. Raw state is really more or less meant to be for internal usage. Power users can also make use of that, if they want to implement their own operators.